# Android Manifest: Does Activity package still need to be under the apk's main package?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm coming into a large preexisting Android project. The manifest looks something like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.company.group1.package1">
    <application ... >
    <activity android:name="com.company.group1.MyActivity />
    <service android:name="com.company.group2.blah.MyService" />
    <provider android:name="com.company.group3.etc.MyProvider" />
    ... more fully-qualified activities ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Basically the entities are all over the place, package-wise, and all fully-qualified. This breaks all kinds of convention of course but somehow it works just fine. I've tried to find a statement from Google that this is a bad idea but I have not found any official recommendation against it or what kind of problems it would cause.

Renaming the package com.company is not a good option because the company has multiple apps.

My question is: Is there any reason other than convention to organize the project in a more sensible way? I anticipate pushback on a massive renaming because of issues with source control history and whatnot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, an activity's name doesn't have to be under the apk's main package.  It is possible, for example, to specify an Activity that is defined in an external jar that uses a totally different package name.

The actual requirement according to the [AndroidManifest.xml documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm) is that an activity name "should be a fully qualified class name".

However, as the doc continues to mention, in most cases, there is a shorthand where you don't have to specify the fully qualified class name all the time.  And this is by preceding the name with a '.'. (ie. "`<activity android:name=".MyActivity />`")